# form input disables after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Hello I have a form button which sends data by ajax after success if it receives true then it add some classes to button else it adds those close which were there at start so that user can send data again but instead it disables the form
 The website is online at https://arpitpatidar.com/ 
what I am not sure is if it works good when page loaded then it get diabled on changing the classes

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
<button type="submit" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
```

Ajax with required variables

```
var btn = document.getElementById("submitbutton")
success : function(r){
if (r == 'true'){
   btn.classList.add('success');
   setTimeout(function(){
      $(form)[0].reset();
   }, 3500);
} else {
   $(btn).addClass('error');
   setTimeout(function(){
      btn.classList.remove('animate', 'error', 'sub-button');
          btn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
   },3500);
}
```

animate[animate.css] success and error[custom classes with spinning animation]
CSS classes

```
.display-t .display-tc .btn {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #00dfc0 !important;
  color: #000;
  border: none !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: You haven't properly closed the first `setTimeout`

Comment: oops! sorry I forget here but in code that is also present. you can even the website at https://arpitpatidar.com/

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: ooh! really..? actually when it return something else I want to make button as it was before sending but instead it disables the button